# Ruby method introspection

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, introspection

I am playing with introspection and would like to extract argument count and argument names at runtime. Would it be possible to implement something like this?

```
class Greeter
   def self.greet(name, weekday = "Friday")
     "Hello #{name}. Today is #{weekday}"
   end

   def self.splatter(*arguments)
     arguments.join("|")
   end
end

Greeter.argument_count(:greet)
=> 1..2

Greeter.argument_names(:greet)
=> [:name, :weekday]

Greeter.argument_count(:splatter)
=> [0..Infinity]
```

I have no idea on how to retrieve the names of the arguments.

I have however managed to extract the arguments count by by deliberately invoking the method with a flood of random arguments solely to trigger `ArgumentError` and then extract the permitted number of arguments from the exception message. However, this is dangerous and does not work for splat method signatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an established format for these things. You can modify the following to meet your needs.

```
class Object
  def argument_count m; method(m).arity end
  def argument_names m; method(m).parameters end
end

Greeter.argument_count(:greet) # => -2
Greeter.argument_names(:greet) # => [[:req, :name], [:opt, :weekday]]
```

Comment: The result of `arity` can be a bit hard to interpret - take a look at the rubydoc page on [Method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Method.html#method-i-arity) for an explanation of how it's calculated.